# CSV impor failing - Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, bulkinsert

I am running a Bulk Insert via a stored procedure. I am getting the below error. It is running for other files but fails throws up an error for the CSV example rows below. I am hopping it is something relatively straightfoward with the BULK INSERT statement.

Please can someone put me out of my misery?

> 

Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 5, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 6, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 10, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 12, column 7 (bbg_ticker_tri).
>
> Msg 4865, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> Cannot bulk load because the maximum number of errors (10) was exceeded.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_eur_hy_indices]
(
    [dte] [datetime] NULL,
    [fixing] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [price_type] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isin_cpi] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [isin_tri] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [bbg_ticker_cpi] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [bbg_ticker_tri] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [cpi_today] [float] NOT NULL,
    [tri_today] [float] NOT NULL,
    [cpi_previous_eom] [float] NOT NULL,
    [tri_previous_eom] [float] NOT NULL,
    [cost_factor_tri] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [cash] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [cost_factor_cpi] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [interest_on_cash] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [simple_margin] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [discount_margin] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [duration] [float] NULL,
    [duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [portfolio_duration] [float] NULL,
    [portfolio_duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_yield] [float] NULL,
    [annual_yield_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_modified_duration] [float] NULL,
    [annual_modified_duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_convexity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_convexity_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_yield] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_yield_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_modified_duration] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_modified_duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_convexity] [float] NULL,
    [annual_portfolio_convexity_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_yield] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_yield_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_modified_duration] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_modified_duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_convexity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_convexity_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_yield] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_yield_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_modified_duration] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_modified_duration_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_convexity] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_portfolio_convexity_to_maturity] [float] NULL,
    [oas] [float] NULL,
    [effective_oa_duration] [float] NULL,
    [oa_convexity] [float] NULL,
    [z_spread] [float] NULL,
    [z_spread_over_libor] [float] NULL,
    [expected_remaining_life] [float] NULL,
    [coupon] [float] NULL,
    [nominal_value] [float] NULL,
    [market_value] [float] NULL,
    [base_market_value] [float] NULL,
    [level_0] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_1] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_2] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_4] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_5] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_6] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_7] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [level_8] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [markit_iboxx_rating] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [seniority_level_1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [seniority_level_2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [seniority_level_3] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [paid_cash] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [annual_index_benchmark_spread] [float] NULL,
    [semi_annual_index_benchmark_spread] [float] NULL,
    [annual_benchmark_spread_to_bm_curve] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [semi_annual_benchmark_spread_to_bm_curve] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [asset_swap_margin] [float] NULL,
    [dv_01] [float] NULL,
    [fx_version] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [index_currency] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [tax_consideration] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [daily_return] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [month_to_date_return] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [quarter_to_date_return] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [year_to_date_return] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [1_3_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [1_5_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [1_10_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [1_15_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [1_20_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [3_5_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [5_7_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [5_10_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [5_15_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [7_10_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [10_15_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [15_20_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [15_25_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [20_25_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [25_30_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [5_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [7_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [10_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [15_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [25_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [30_years] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [gross_price_index] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [coupon_income_index] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [redemption_income_index] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [income_index] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [number_of_bonds] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [daily_sovereign_curve_swap_return] [float] NULL,
    [daily_libor_swap_return] [float] NULL,
    [month_to_date_sovereign_curve_swap_return] [float] NULL,
    [month_to_date_libor_swap_return] [float] NULL,
    [duration_weighted_exposure] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [upload_datetime] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The view is

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_eur_hy_indices] AS 

SELECT
       [dte]
      ,[fixing]
      ,[price_type]
      ,[isin_cpi]
      ,[isin_tri]
      ,[bbg_ticker_cpi]
      ,[bbg_ticker_tri]
      ,[name]
      ,[cpi_today]
      ,[tri_today]
      ,[cpi_previous_eom]
      ,[tri_previous_eom]
      ,[cost_factor_tri]
      ,[cash]
      ,[cost_factor_cpi]
      ,[interest_on_cash]
      ,[simple_margin]
      ,[discount_margin]
      ,[duration]
      ,[duration_to_maturity]
      ,[portfolio_duration]
      ,[portfolio_duration_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_yield]
      ,[annual_yield_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_modified_duration]
      ,[annual_modified_duration_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_convexity]
      ,[annual_convexity_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_portfolio_yield]
      ,[annual_portfolio_yield_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_portfolio_modified_duration]
      ,[annual_portfolio_modified_duration_to_maturity]
      ,[annual_portfolio_convexity]
      ,[annual_portfolio_convexity_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_yield]
      ,[semi_annual_yield_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_modified_duration]
      ,[semi_annual_modified_duration_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_convexity]
      ,[semi_annual_convexity_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_yield]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_yield_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_modified_duration]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_modified_duration_to_maturity]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_convexity]
      ,[semi_annual_portfolio_convexity_to_maturity]
      ,[oas]
      ,[effective_oa_duration]
      ,[oa_convexity]
      ,[z_spread]
      ,[z_spread_over_libor]
      ,[expected_remaining_life]
      ,[coupon]
      ,[nominal_value]
      ,[market_value]
      ,[base_market_value]
      ,[level_0]
      ,[level_1]
      ,[level_2]
      ,[level_3]
      ,[level_4]
      ,[level_5]
      ,[level_6]
      ,[level_7]
      ,[level_8]
      ,[markit_iboxx_rating]
      ,[seniority_level_1]
      ,[seniority_level_2]
      ,[seniority_level_3]
      ,[paid_cash]
      ,[annual_index_benchmark_spread]
      ,[semi_annual_index_benchmark_spread]
      ,[annual_benchmark_spread_to_bm_curve]
      ,[semi_annual_benchmark_spread_to_bm_curve]
      ,[asset_swap_margin]
      ,[dv_01]
      ,[fx_version]
      ,[index_currency]
      ,[tax_consideration]
      ,[daily_return]
      ,[month_to_date_return]
      ,[quarter_to_date_return]
      ,[year_to_date_return]
      ,[1_3_years]
      ,[1_5_years]
      ,[1_10_years]
      ,[1_15_years]
      ,[1_20_years]
      ,[3_5_years]
      ,[5_7_years]
      ,[5_10_years]
      ,[5_15_years]
      ,[7_10_years]
      ,[10_15_years]
      ,[15_20_years]
      ,[15_25_years]
      ,[20_25_years]
      ,[25_30_years]
      ,[5_years]
      ,[7_years]
      ,[10_years]
      ,[15_years]
      ,[25_years]
      ,[30_years]
      ,[gross_price_index]
      ,[coupon_income_index]
      ,[redemption_income_index]
      ,[income_index]
      ,[number_of_bonds]
      ,[daily_sovereign_curve_swap_return]
      ,[daily_libor_swap_return]
      ,[month_to_date_sovereign_curve_swap_return]
      ,[month_to_date_libor_swap_return]
      ,[duration_weighted_exposure]

  FROM [dbo].[tbl_eur_hy_indices]
```

The stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_import_eur_hy_indices]
     @Filepath varchar(500)
    ,@Pattern varchar(100)
    ,@TableName varchar(128)
    ,@ViewName varchar(128)
    ,@ResetTable bit = 0 
AS
  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
  
DECLARE @query varchar(1000)
DECLARE @numfiles int
DECLARE @filename varchar(100)
DECLARE @files TABLE (Name varchar(200) NULL)
  
--Delete the contents of the rawData table and let the user know
IF @ResetTable = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Emptying table [' + @TableName + ']...'
    EXEC ('DELETE ' + @TableName)
END
  
--Pull a list of the CSV file names from the folder that they're stored in
SET @query = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell "dir ' + @filepath+@pattern + ' /b"'
INSERT @files(Name) 
EXEC (@query)
 
DECLARE curs_files CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name FROM @files WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
  
--For each CSV file, execute a query
SET @numfiles =0
OPEN curs_files
FETCH NEXT FROM curs_files INTO @filename
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @numfiles+=1
  
    --BULK INSERT each CSV file into the rawData view and update the rawData table with the file name and the upload datetime
    SET @query = ('BULK INSERT ' + @ViewName
    + ' FROM ''' + @Filepath+@filename + ''' WITH(
    CODEPAGE = ''65001'',
    DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR='','',
    ROWTERMINATOR=''0x0a'');'
  
    + ' UPDATE ' + @TableName
    + ' SET [filename] = ' + '''' + @filename + ''''
    + ' WHERE [filename] Is Null;'
  
    + ' UPDATE ' + @TableName
    + ' SET [upload_datetime] = ' + '''' + CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(1000)) + ''''
    + ' WHERE [upload_datetime] Is Null;'
    )
  
    PRINT 'Importing [' + @filename + '] into [' + @TableName + ']...'
    EXEC (@query)
  
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs_files INTO @filename
END
  
CLOSE curs_files
DEALLOCATE curs_files
```

and the first 10 rows of the csv are below. The Row terminator is line feed '0x0a' and the field separator is ','

```
Date,Fixing,Price Type,ISIN_CPi,ISIN_TRi,BBG_Ticker_CPi,BBG_Ticker_TRi,Name,CPi_Today,TRi_Today,CPi_previous_EOM,TRi_previous_EOM,Cost Factor_TRi,Cash,Cost Factor_CPi,Interest on Cash,Simple Margin,Discount Margin,Duration,Duration to Maturity,Portfolio Duration,Portfolio Duration to Maturity,Annual Yield,Annual Yield to Maturity,Annual Modified Duration,Annual Modified Duration to Maturity,Annual Convexity,Annual Convexity to Maturity,Annual Portfolio Yield,Annual Portfolio Yield to Maturity,Annual Portfolio Modified Duration,Annual Portfolio Modified Duration to Maturity,Annual Portfolio Convexity,Annual Portfolio Convexity to Maturity,Semi-Annual Yield,Semi-Annual Yield to Maturity,Semi-Annual Modified Duration,Semi-Annual Modified Duration to Maturity,Semi-Annual Convexity,Semi-Annual Convexity to Maturity,Semi-Annual Portfolio Yield,Semi-Annual Portfolio Yield to Maturity,Semi-Annual Portfolio Modified Duration,Semi-Annual Portfolio Modified Duration to Maturity,Semi-Annual Portfolio Convexity,Semi-Annual Portfolio Convexity to Maturity,OAS,Effective OA duration,OA Convexity,z-spread,Z-Spread Over Libor,Expected Remaining Life,Coupon,Nominal Value,Market Value,Base Market Value,Level 0,Level 1,Level 2,Level 3,Level 4,Level 5,Level 6,Level 7,Level 8,Markit iBoxx Rating,Seniority Level 1,Seniority Level 2,Seniority Level 3,Paid Cash,Annual Index Benchmark Spread,Semi-annual Index Benchmark Spread,Annual Benchmark Spread to BM-Curve,Semi-Annual Benchmark Spread to BM-Curve,Asset Swap Margin,DV 01,FX Version,Index Currency,Tax Consideration,Daily Return,Month-to-Date Return,Quarter-to-Date Return,Year-to-Date Return,1-3 Years,1-5 Years,1-10 Years,1-15 Years,1-20 Years,3-5 Years,5-7 Years,5-10 Years,5-15 Years,7-10 Years,10-15 Years,15-20 Years,15-25 Years,20-25 Years,25-30 Years,5+ Years,7+ Years,10+ Years,15+ Years,25+ Years,30+ Years,Gross Price Index,Coupon Income Index,Redemption Income Index,Income Index,Number of Bonds,Daily Sovereign Curve Swap Return,Daily Libor Swap Return,Month-to-date Sovereign Curve Swap Return,Month-to-date Libor Swap Return,Duration weighted exposure
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KT9M89,GB00B1CTQK32,IBXXHCX2,IBXXHCX1,iBoxx EUR High Yield cum-crossover,122.688755979648,375.674735085899,122.050527013077,373.458235576939,1,0,1,0,,,3.45444819830822,4.14982765499078,3.44891477023608,4.1431803493945,2.71975655259125,2.9367983320229,3.36466570544599,4.0332980138925,19.0823044120007,24.4449677778724,2.7153999733654,2.93209408943486,3.35927609338667,4.02683736861076,19.0517378633501,24.4058111707503,2.68834134825912,2.90341547463045,3.40906583055825,4.09092863712993,17.901742287252,23.1253155079009,2.68403509075285,2.89876470560161,3.40360509718386,4.08437567756523,17.8730667947779,23.0882727552924,339.452364530924,3.42369130628568,-39.1163300238647,348.526987012627,321.479453488336,4.5280230759434,3.64076932223501,432143270500,448982825752.599,447049901445.438,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,720346641.60765,342.399613775266,339.382417745424,,,312.095867966326,0.0360811693466207,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00111131363415717,0.00593506662274046,0.00593506662274046,0.00593506662274046,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54.2184658868672,0.0317293577429768,0.0552585793774614,0.0869879371204382,782,0.00101358198814322,0.00115665711391235,0.0067345251237787,0.00626360056687547,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KT9N96,GB00B1CTQL49,IBXXHEX2,IBXXHEX1,iBoxx EUR High Yield ex-crossover,114.373650207173,364.293817733864,113.785271279766,362.149644301914,1,0,1,0,,,3.35257163246533,4.16175814591435,3.34657732377441,4.15431703331231,3.07707768591167,3.27287277236213,3.25429964569763,4.03184763890315,18.311658120494,24.4925942353031,3.07157595305182,3.2670209631081,3.24848104469887,4.02463880282391,18.2789173640091,24.448802129844,3.03894658115768,3.23348527902885,3.30285896572084,4.09605425953217,17.2258287015459,23.2484160104455,3.03351302569647,3.22770389356273,3.29695354195259,4.08873062372715,17.1950293791111,23.2068484624795,374.80019216287,3.31461270234828,-49.9747974918777,385.134014495595,358.127515053145,4.56327825098089,3.81475237813724,355613998500,367064889966.953,365558014443.218,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,657477789.15265,378.032324350432,374.343524974372,,,345.775854709102,0.0347311781950243,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00117315090405512,0.00592068352319641,0.00592068352319641,0.00592068352319641,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,43.9751042628257,0.0239462360974358,0.0548209113981555,0.0787671474955913,674,0.00107282934452984,0.00121770470412718,0.00672051106773019,0.00623843862347351,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMR47,GB00B1CQNQ99,IEHZKTMR,IEHNCQNQ,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 10+,54.5375490059183,198.104393448492,54.3255996094595,197.181589253972,1,0,1,0,,,10.4901713936517,10.9207765753727,10.4901713936517,10.9207765753727,3.33173626296297,3.32950422367245,10.152130573038,10.5690747409849,173.154292841605,180.892779210843,3.33173626296297,3.32950422367245,10.152130573038,10.5690747409849,173.154292841605,180.892779210843,3.30394983247616,3.30178589925606,10.3197421898231,10.7434624991524,174.202757782898,181.972136946542,3.30394983247616,3.30178589925606,10.3197421898231,10.7434624991524,174.202757782898,181.972136946542,372.340371502719,10.3101987525551,162.094230918578,376.193319683536,348.67498467349,16.9601092778577,5.49193548387097,2635000000,3436419809.447,3420412377.41035,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,0,367.528904130438,364.788824263827,,,400.001925742914,0.139057398692438,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00113413114081684,0.00467997138075171,0.00467997138075171,0.00467997138075171,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,67.5504936510861,0,0,0,3,-0.000317281851484679,0.000910890083274132,0.00909492847561366,0.0119987174109089,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMS53,GB00B1CQNP82,IEHZKTMS,IEHNCQNP,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 1-10,120.442231225853,377.30283288268,119.814492206631,375.073119398183,1,0,1,0,,,3.40018292259339,4.0976045359433,3.39469447799169,4.09099034017584,2.70519423175773,2.9287259042799,3.31231520184908,3.98288873594634,17.8939746980631,23.2383137656718,2.70082761119176,2.92399846747866,3.30696858994537,3.97645971001461,17.8650909317863,23.2008033726596,2.67369267918876,2.89522660724617,3.35576501874409,4.03961883226668,16.6962204858833,21.900158360232,2.66937690721832,2.8905532437228,3.35034827181576,4.03309823479365,16.6692700884251,21.8648079662488,338.676450470778,3.37057690497844,-40.6682311238834,347.874265899717,320.835872659402,4.45169580767204,3.62940401685189,429508270500,445546405943.152,443629489068.029,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,720346641.60765,341.801651486208,338.777861357887,,,310.004105453849,0.0352869320916326,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00111113793491358,0.00594474348914886,0.00594474348914886,0.00594474348914886,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51.7208927519195,0.0305011948784999,0.053119660093784,0.0836208549722839,779,0.00102388107814451,0.00115856334882811,0.00671632625955021,0.00621938244088893,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMT60,GB00B1CQNN68,IEHZKTMT,IEHNCQNN,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 5+,130.321758489433,436.495734864776,129.647920694138,433.942599673784,1,0,1,0,,,4.74494527754415,5.8337514984905,4.74396939927502,5.83255168880211,2.5864216704344,2.82340554734993,4.62600640972736,5.67451641599486,32.9020624157439,42.751669201282,2.58588972906198,2.82282486623404,4.62505499324855,5.67334935569505,32.8952955499861,42.7428765972577,2.56609600775713,2.79946509254889,4.68501160720455,5.75346326349844,31.439906906408,41.1125771102824,2.5655682467011,2.79888933519255,4.68404805530865,5.75227996644386,31.4334407576669,41.104121613276,323.281775806835,4.76087733018983,-49.7443700195032,333.249971286634,303.615379514612,6.5387809097932,3.54276085288725,157793471000,166163439849.033,165225504038.693,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,34181352.455,325.998809305485,324.082224943165,,,300.616537501538,0.0508317284285612,Local,EUR,Gross,0.000991904379388231,0.00588357813432316,0.00588357813432316,0.00588357813432316,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,93.3253380574262,0.0191978829760696,0,0.0191978829760696,263,0.000892557309840591,0.00102745323628433,0.00671826839926282,0.00673835742961026,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMW99,GB00B1CQNM51,,,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 5-10,133.977636468576,448.947615779626,133.281342093393,446.310358371987,1,0,1,0,,,4.62361933652746,5.72632524720721,4.6226483338511,5.72512266612602,2.55071193114792,2.8030229627168,4.5093073972361,5.57115461915007,29.9402583905899,39.8344471761974,2.55017625813259,2.80243430205929,4.5083604011206,5.56998462533097,29.9339706603698,39.8260815751381,2.53074373104555,2.77923465758691,4.56601907732047,5.64808597447566,28.4250843607376,38.1379476870093,2.53021225153628,2.77865099269273,4.56506017122944,5.64689982436287,28.4191148310292,38.1299383664793,320.98157570742,4.64368844502394,-54.2179132853485,331.236495506282,301.496055953189,6.36179927242034,3.5096587275599,155158471000,162727020039.586,161805091661.283,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,34181352.455,324.009006779668,322.13187798424,,,295.854754573145,0.0489686055069789,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00098890194418999,0.00590902128568027,0.00590902128568027,0.00590902128568027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,94.3425619302346,0.0198169693027043,0,0.0198169693027043,260,0.000918225549439511,0.00102993071846384,0.00666802796826982,0.00662715820710758,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMX07,GB00B1CQNH09,IEHUKTMX,IEHNCQNH,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 1-5,119.259198853489,343.783167049926,118.636604682551,341.744574259032,1,0,1,0,,,2.69624899242322,3.16048041705031,2.68972329138587,3.15283114192994,2.85761751089283,3.05977041848396,2.62359659670937,3.06904128741107,10.9628520610005,13.6893243092167,2.85070125144958,3.05236489063765,2.61724673544624,3.06161332138523,10.9363187937585,13.6561921919322,2.81473632845403,3.0161474743768,2.6594158777057,3.11414809748293,9.94773306976338,12.5573508976699,2.80792385385317,3.00884752665029,2.65297932344063,3.10661095995323,9.9236566835709,12.5269584828708,356.59802656698,2.63806118146205,-32.872091571517,364.725194327564,340.420751820953,3.37016428530146,3.69720573933174,274349799500,282819385903.567,281824397406.745,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,686165289.15265,359.357146451981,355.201978297006,,,323.96486633297,0.0274148481574949,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00118132739397514,0.00596525283631588,0.00596525283631588,0.00596525283631588,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35.7406312404901,0.0288849035238741,0.0578276126329609,0.086712516156835,519,0.00108454705372707,0.00123247784771872,0.00674405597180683,0.00598526433103919,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTMY14,GB00B1CQNL45,,,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped cum-crossover 7-10,149.665008876674,500.146340112832,148.779321978934,496.87337172777,1,0,1,0,,,5.99553153838748,7.06245276473613,5.99553153838748,7.06245276473613,2.50081111654366,2.63604641347712,5.84974901899678,6.88166850402487,46.5843698441546,58.5830082607,2.50081111654366,2.63604641347712,5.84974901899678,6.88166850402487,46.5843698441546,58.5830082607,2.48321113827053,2.61666825965841,5.9221292110512,6.97139850177188,44.7986640249893,56.6604134903248,2.48321113827053,2.61666825965841,5.9221292110512,6.97139850177188,44.7986640249893,56.6604134903248,311.661922658089,6.06412521443129,-48.332055335298,320.071708800391,288.883492879454,7.96929156220228,3.29379649813373,44476113000,46925585842.2916,46618503801.308,EUR,Corporates,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,0,314.492678161897,312.837016317403,,,286.895873234519,0.0645391381949309,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00114754280142582,0.00658712776996051,0.00658712776996051,0.00658712776996051,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,119.135626395357,0,0,0,67,0.00101647649883609,0.00113662405909579,0.00737718524489495,0.0080243547803962,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTQK57,GB00B1CQQJ38,IEHUKTN0,IEHNCQNK,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped Energy cum-crossover 5-7,369.320187556911,833.351263025133,366.059529455024,825.546722701596,1,0,1,0,,,4.82744175096773,5.000718381173,4.82744175096773,5.000718381173,2.10332668584449,2.1330384490561,4.72811338263585,4.89640266905831,28.4929202029868,30.3757706538588,2.10332668584449,2.1330384490561,4.72811338263585,4.89640266905831,28.4929202029868,30.3757706538588,2.09175550158252,2.12114298682928,4.77750471734478,4.94827004934737,26.7200243458836,28.5685765982595,2.09175550158252,2.12114298682928,4.77750471734478,4.94827004934737,26.7200243458836,28.5685765982595,282.548718458616,4.86403991740211,17.0917423994373,284.87468413518,256.42979418156,5.42444824927957,3.24301075268817,6510000000,6967614711.5622,6902361279.5606,EUR,Corporates,Non-Financials,Energy,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,0,282.610276170282,281.584308569032,,,258.869936037151,0.0522391650351495,Local,EUR,Gross,0.000883440813008063,0.00945378390940355,0.00945378390940355,0.00945378390940355,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,248.185374864463,0,0,0,9,0.000855259598383011,0.000971047051461869,0.0102399296481475,0.00996434402159574,
2021-01-08,EU_EOD,Nominal,GB00B1KTQM71,GB00B1CQQH14,IEHUKTQM,IEHNCQQH,iBoxx EUR High Yield Capped Energy cum-crossover 3-5,161.219759109027,365.599164341714,160.077876561523,362.781265167013,1,0,1,0,,,3.21534702255882,3.72248721242423,3.21237581231339,3.71904736843027,1.79450024945601,2.02297118667983,3.15931429052933,3.64943732414798,14.4763688159055,17.8041149240089,1.79284200308658,2.0211018168501,3.15639485852939,3.64606498346702,14.4629916174132,17.7876626504901,1.78115407902083,2.00742205987485,3.18712841633795,3.68568779104986,13.1472139777927,16.3345611896968,1.77950816546589,2.0055670585486,3.18418328209965,3.68228195234897,13.1350650132811,16.3194668887641,253.693803177955,3.25552519333661,-0.998637478608128,261.015131727145,235.763686799445,4.01306386224404,3.79757606852054,13062828000,14190322815.8992,14093973047.404,EUR,Corporates,Non-Financials,Energy,*,*,*,*,*,*,,,*,13125000,253.316112565561,252.118411536292,,,232.783142866128,0.0355796079861918,Local,EUR,Gross,0.00142191953266102,0.00776748814028094,0.00776748814028094,0.00776748814028094,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0.00133822741572676,0.00147211238710031,0.00858815469319651,0.00780085631978156,
```

Comment: Careful, statements like `EXEC ('DELETE ' + @TableName)` are huge security vulnerabilities. Imagine if some said the table's name was `#t; DROP PROC dbo.usp_import_eur_hy_indices;`. What do you think would happen?

Comment: Thanks Lamu - noted - what are your thoughts on the bulk insert error please?

Comment: That's a heck wide table. Are you sure there are no special characters anywhere?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface - I looked at the file in Notepad++ and it dis not look like it. Only Linefeeds at the end. Although the position of the column that is bugging does change after the first error so was thinking something could be pushing the layout out of whack, but cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to create a table from the CSV I was reading. I then red the CSV row  into a dictionary and appended the row dictionary to a list. I then used SQL alchemy to bulk insert my list of row dictonaries session.bulk_insert_mappings:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session,sessionmaker,mapper
from sqlalchemy import MetaData,create_engine
from datetime import datetime


import urllib
import os
import glob
import chardet
import re
import csv

def rtn_date(dtStr):
        if dtStr =='':
                return None
        else:
                try:
                        # rtnDate =datetime.strptime(dtStr,'%d/%m/%Y')
                        rtnDate =datetime.strftime(dtStr,'%F')
                        return rtnDate
                except:
                        return None


log_file =r'XXXXXX.txt'
database = 'XXXXXXX'
driver_name ='ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server'


engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:{0}?driver={1}?Trusted_Connection=yes'.format(database,driver_name))
connection= engine.connect()

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

date_test_table = Base.classes.XXXXXXXXX
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

#define folder where all csv files are
folder =r'XXXXXXX'
os.chdir(folder)
extension ='csv'

skipped =[]
all_filenames =[i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

for i in range(len(all_filenames)):

    try:

        with open(all_filenames[i], 'r') as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

                buffer = []

                firstline= True

                for row in csv_reader :
                    if firstline:    #skip first line
                        firstline = False
                        continue

                    if len(re.findall(r'\d+',str(all_filenames[i]))) > 0:
                        strType = 'Normal'
                    else:
                        strType = 'MonthEnd'

                    buffer.append({
                        'Date': row[0],
                        'ISIN': row[1],
                        'CUSIP': row[2],
                        'Ticker': row[3],
                        'Issuer': row[4],
                        'Coupon': row[5],
                        'Final_Maturity':  row[6],
                        'Workout_date':  row[7],
                        'Expected_Remaining_Life': row[8],
                        'Time_to_Maturity': row[9],
                        'Coupon_Frequency': row[10],
                        'Notional_Amount_Unconstrained': row[11],
                        'Notional_Amount_Constrained': row[12],
                        'PIK_Original_Amount_Issued': row[13],
                        'PIK_Factor': row[14],
                        'Redemption_Factor': row[15],
                        'Bid_Price': row[16],
                        'Ask_Price': row[17],
                        'Accrued_Interest': row[18],
                        'Coupon_Payment': row[19],
                        'Coupon_Adjustment': row[20],
                        'Ex_Dividend_Flag': row[21],
                        'Dirty_Price': row[22],
                        'Market_Value_Unconstrained': row[23],
                        'Market_Value_Constrained': row[24],
                        'Cash_Payment_Unconstrained': row[25],
                        'Cash_Payment_Constrained': row[26],
                        'Street_Yield_to_Maturity': row[27],
                        'Annual_Yield_to_Maturity': row[28],
                        'Semi_Annual_Yield_to_Maturity': row[29],
                        'Street_Yield_to_Worst': row[30],
                        'Annual_Yield_to_Worst': row[31],
                        'Semi_Annual_Yield_to_Worst': row[32],
                        'OAS_Street_Yield': row[33],
                        'OAS_Annual_Yield': row[34],
                        'OAS_Semi_Annual_Yield': row[35],
                        'Annual_Benchmark_Spread': row[36],
                        'Semi_Annual_Benchmark_Spread': row[37],
                        'Z_Spread': row[38],
                        'OAS_Spread': row[39],
                        'Asset_Swap_Margin': row[40],
                        'Simple_Margin': row[41],
                        'Discount_Margin': row[42],
                        'Duration_to_Maturity': row[43],
                        'Street_Modified_Duration_to_Maturity': row[44],
                        'Annual_Modified_Duration_to_Maturity': row[45],
                        'Semi_Annual_Modified_Duration_to_Maturity': row[46],
                        'Duration_to_Worst': row[47],
                        'Street_Modified_Duration_to_Worst': row[48],
                        'Annual_Modified_Duration_to_Worst': row[49],
                        'Semi_Annual_Modified_Duration_to_Worst': row[50],
                        'OAS_Duration': row[51],
                        'OAS_Modified_Duration': row[52],
                        'OAS_Annual_Modified_Duration': row[53],
                        'OAS_Semi_Annual_Modified_Duration': row[54],
                        'Spread_Duration': row[55],
                        'Z_Spread_Duration': row[56],
                        'Street_Convexity_to_Maturity': row[57],
                        'Annual_Convexity_to_Maturity': row[58],
                        'Semi_Annual_Convexity_to_Maturity': row[59],
                        'Street_Convexity_to_Worst': row[60],
                        'Annual_Convexity_to_Worst': row[61],
                        'Semi_Annual_Convexity_to_Worst': row[62],
                        'OAS_Convexity': row[63],
                        'Benchmark_ISIN': row[64],
                        'Daily_Return': row[65],
                        'Month_to_Date_Return': row[66],
                        'Quarter_to_Date_Return': row[67],
                        'Year_to_Date_Return': row[68],
                        'Daily_Excess_Return': row[69],
                        'Month_to_date_Excess_Return': row[70],
                        'Level_0': row[71],
                        'Level_1': row[72],
                        'Level_2': row[73],
                        'Level_3': row[74],
                        'Level_4': row[75],
                        'Level_5': row[76],
                        'Debt': row[77],
                        'Rating': row[78],
                        'Is_Callable': row[79],
                        'Is_Core_index': row[80],
                        'Is_Crossover': row[81],
                        'Is_Fixed_to_Float': row[82],
                        'Is_FRN': row[83],
                        'Is_Hybrid': row[84],
                        'Is_Perpetual': row[85],
                        'Is_PIK': row[86],
                        'Is_Sinking': row[87],
                        'Is_Zero_Coupon': row[88],
                        '_1_3_years': row[89],
                        '_1_5_years': row[90],
                        '_1_10_years': row[91],
                        '_3_5_years': row[92],
                        '_5_7_years': row[93],
                        '_5_10_years': row[94],
                        '_7_10_years': row[95],
                        '_5_years': row[96],
                        '_10_years': row[97],
                        'Source':str(all_filenames[i]),
                        'File_Type': strType
                    })

                session.bulk_insert_mappings(date_test_table,buffer)
                session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            skipped.append('{0} {1}'.format(str(all_filenames[i]),r'\n'))

    print('processed {0} out of {1} files'.format(str(i+1), str(len(all_filenames)+1)))

session.close()

if len(skipped)>0:

    open(log_file, 'w').close()
    skip_log = open(log_file,'w')
    skip_log.writelines(skipped)
    skip_log.close()
```